# Flask SocketIO: send a message to the client when being called in a loop

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask-socketio

I'm coaching multiple athletics that are doing multiple sprint per person per training. I have two files running at the same time: socketIO and a datafeed on which all the trainingresults are coming in every 6s.

I have my socketIO and my datafeed up and running, however the part to send messages from my datafeed via the server to the client is not working. I would like to send a message to the client whenever a function is being called in the datafeed file. Eventually I would like to present my data in some sort of js-chart on a html page.

**(Process 1)** This is the part in my socketio which I would like to call for sending a message to the client:

```
def sendMessage(timestamp, position, logOfRace):
    @socketio.on('my event', namespace='/test')
    def message():
        emit('my response', {'data': timestamp, position, logOfRace})
```

This is my corresponding js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test');
    socket.on('my response', function(msg) {
        $('#log').append('<p>Received: ' + msg.data + '</p>');
    });
    $('form#emit').submit(function(event) {
        socket.emit('my event', {data: $('#emit_data').val()});
        return false;
    });
});
```

**(Process 2)** This is datafeed that collects data every 6s. At the end of each loop, I would like to send the data to my client with sendMessage.

```
from socketIO import sendMessage

#infiniteloop of data collection. Example of one 6s loop:
data = [ 
[50, 3, 0.148, 8.155, 12.177], 
[52, 1, 0.232, 7.148, 11.256], 
[56, 3, 1.121, 8.141, 12.368], 
[57, 6, 1.653, 8.650, 14.540] ]

for i in range(len(data)):
    timestamp = data[i][0]
    position = data[i][1]
    logOfRace = data[i][2:5]
    sendMessage(timestamp, position, logOfRace)
```

**QUESTION:**  How can I use the sendMessage function in the for-loop of the datafeed file?
Eventually the output in my browser must be:

> 50 3 [0.148, 8.155, 12.177]
>
> 52 1 [0.232, 7.148, 11.256]
>
> 56 3 [1.121, 8.141, 12.368]
>
> 57 6 [1.653, 8.65, 14.54]

and this should be updated every 6s!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why are you putting your event handler inside the `sendMessage()` function? Event handlers are global, if you hide it inside a function then the handler will not be registered with the server. Besides that, I suggest you read the Flask-SocketIO documentation, specifically the section on [emitting from an external process](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#emitting-from-an-external-process).

Comment: Thank you for the link, I had a look and I improved my code. Eventually I used the option to start a thread on connection of the socket using this example: https://github.com/shanealynn/async_flask/blob/master/application.py